# ActionBar doesn't show in Android KitKat 4.4.4

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm developing an app in Android and I'm having problem with implementing the ActionBar in a Fragment.

Here's the code of my Fragment:

```
public class TopicListFragment extends ListFragment {

private LinkedList<Topic> mTopics;
private static final String TAG = "TopicListFragment";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setHasOptionsMenu(true); 

    mTopics = TopicLab.get(getActivity()).getTopics();

    ArrayAdapter<Topic> adapter =  new TopicAdapter(mTopics);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Menu created");
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_topic_list, menu);
    }
```

And here's the XML file for the meny layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

        <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_new_topic"
              android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
              android:title="@string/new_topic"
              app:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>

    </menu>
```

When I run the app the ActionBar doesn't show and if I press the menù button from my smartphone, it appears in an ugly botton line with only the title.

As you can see in the Fragment class, I have inserted a line of debug, but it print the message only when I press the menù button but not when the Activity is created.

What can I do to fix it? Every answer will be really appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT----

As asked this is the styles.xml file

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Show us the style.xml

Comment: put activity code also where you are inflating toolbar or action bar. may be you have issue in it also.

Comment: @Shahzeb I've edited the post with the styles.xml file.

Comment: @androidnoobdev Maybe i am missing it, I am just new in Android. I have inflated the action bar only in the Fragment..

Comment: add your activity code

Comment: By inflate action bar they mean inflate Toolbar and set it as an action bar. Your theme is fine, Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar does provide a default action bar. Post the activity code, maybe you're replacing or obscuring the whole view hierarchy (including the actionbar) with the fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in xml file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
```

And below code in activity which holds fragment

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
if (toolbar != null) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

And in your style add

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Comment: This changed something in my app, thank you! Now the Action Bar appears, but overlays the list on the top. I guess it is because my activity xml has only one FrameLayout that holds the FragmentList. Could be this?

Comment: @thebluebird yes, if you are using CoordinatorLayout put 
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" in frame layout or if you are using relative layout use below attribute. hope it will help. accept the answer also so it might help some one.

Answer (score 0):

Long time after, here is a safe option if you getting a gap in the actionbar testing with the old versions:

```
final RelativeLayout mainLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Rect rectangle = new Rect();
        Window window = activity.getWindow();
        window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
        mainLayout.setPadding(0, rectangle.top, 0, 0);
    }
```